# Retrieve Image from database, display and attach it to a link

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have Images stored in my DB, I want to retrieve them all and display them in the browser. It works just fine, but I want to give the user the ability to click on the picture so that they can have a better view of the picture (so display it with its original size). I tried many things but didn't work. second question: if I want my code to support multiple images type (such gif, jpg, etc..), if there a way to do it without having to save the image type (when I insert the images) and play with a whole bunch of if/else (when I retrieve them)? 

This is my code

```
  $count = 0;
       echo " <div class=\"row\">"; 
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $imagename = base64_encode( $row['Image'] );
       if(($count%3) ==0){
        echo "</div>";
         echo " <div class=\"row\">"; 

            echo "  <div class=\"col-sm-2\">";
            echo " <a href=\"$imagename.jpeg\" class=\"thumbnail\">";
            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'" style=\"width:130px;height:130px\"/>';
            echo"</a></div>";      


        ++$count;

       }else{
                echo "  <div class=\"col-sm-2\">";
            echo " <a href=\"$imagename.jpeg\" class=\"thumbnail\">";
            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'" style=\"width:130px;height:130px\"/>';
            echo"</a></div>";
            ++$count;

       }

   }
 echo "</div>" ;
```

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Comment: Save only the path in the db and the file in a folder in your server. What happens when you click your href link?

Comment: @e4c5 small files (ca. < 100k) is ok

Comment: @Strawberry we are going to have our first disagreement.

Comment: First of many no doubt :-)

Comment: @e4c5 According to some sources, Databases are posweful enough nowadays to store images

Comment: see that linked question. that has a direct quote from the mysql manual advising against storing files in the database.

Comment: Look at all the nasty stuff you have had to do because you have stored files in a database. Your code would be a lot simpler and faster if you hadn't done so

Comment: But in practice, storing tiny files (tiny thumbnails say) can actually perform really well. I avoid the practice myself, but only because it's not widely supported.

Comment: You need to store the type. You won't need _"a whole bunch of if/else"_, though. Save the type and just: `data:image/<?= $row['type'] ?>;base64,`. Simple enough.

Comment: Btw, storing images in databases has major drawbacks. Every time you want to show an image, you need the overhead of connecting to the database and fetch the data, which he otherwise wouldn't need to do to see the larger version. Images won't be cached by the client either, when he shows them in his list.

Comment: Assuming I do store them in the DB like I did, do you guys have a solution to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is "You have to use light-box jQuery plugin", in order to display larger (original size) of a thumbnail you need to use any lightbox plugin, I recommend using this one
http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/Responsive-jQuery-Lightbox-Like-Image-Zooming-Plugin-Lighter.html
Or you can search for any other plugin, there are thousands of them.

Regarding your second question, If you will use data as an images source, you have to specify a type, no way you can do that without mentioning types.